# Build a vector with step c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Is it possible to create a vector from a value to another one with a fixed step without using a loop in c++?

For example, I want to build a vector from 1 to 10 with step 0.5. In MATLAB I can do this as follow:

```
vector = [1:0.5:10];
```

Is there something similar in c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop somewhere. Matlab is simply hiding the loop from you. If this is something you do often, just create a function to make it easier to use:

```
#include <vector>

auto make_vector(double beg, double step, double end) 
{
    std::vector<double> vec;
    vec.reserve((end - beg) / step + 1);
    while (beg <= end) {
        vec.push_back(beg);
        beg += step;
    }
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    auto vec = make_vector(1, 0.5, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the help of [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) you can

```
std::vector<double> v;
const int size = 10 * 2 - 1;
v.reserve(size);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), size, []() { static double d = 0.5; return d += 0.5; });
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rpA7iQCwaVn5bCKy)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible without a loop, but you can *hide* the loop by using e.g, [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) or [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n):

```
constexpr size_t SIZE = (10 - 1) * 2;
std::vector<double> data(SIZE);

double new_value = 1.0;
std::generate(begin(data), end(data) [&new_value]()
{
    double current_value = new_value;
    new_value += 0.5;
    return current_value;
});
```

Of course, this is quite a lot to write, and an explicit loop would probably be better:

```
std::vector<double> data;
for (double i = 1.0; i <= 10; i += 0.5)
    data.push_back(i);
```

---

If the stepping is "one" (e.g. `1` or `1.0`) then you could use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead:

```
std::vector<double> data(10);
std::iota(begin(data), end(data), 1.0);  // Initializes the vector with values from 1.0 to 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such things in C++. You will have to create a loop and populate your vector, so something like:

```
std::vector<double> v;
v.reserve(19);
for(size_t i = 2; i < 21; ++i)
{
    v.push_back(i / 2.);
}
```

I'm using here an integer loop instead of a double loop with .5 increments to make sure about the number of elements I get and minimize numerical rounding errors (.5 is fine, but not 1/3 for instance).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a lot of this, you can easily write your own function that can work with any container (that supports reserve and is fill-able by `std::generate`):

```
template <typename TContainer>
TContainer fill(typename TContainer::value_type start, 
                typename TContainer::value_type step, 
                typename TContainer::value_type end) {
    size_t size = static_cast<size_t>((end - start)/step + 1);
    TContainer output(size);
    std::generate(std::begin(output), std::end(output), 
        [&start, step]() { 
            return std::exchange(start, start + step);
        }
    );
    return output;
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
auto vec = fill<std::vector<int>>(0, 2, 10);
auto list = fill<std::list<float>>(1, 0.3, 5);
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/RKdyTj)

And you will get:

```
vec: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
list: 1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 2.2, 2.5, 2.8, 3.1, 3.4, 3.7, 4, 4.3, 4.6, 4.9
```

Comment: `return std::exchange(start, start + step);`

Comment: @Evg Noooice! Ammended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using [Ranges-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) library:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

auto make_vector(double min, double step, double max) {
    const auto size = static_cast<std::size_t>((max - min) / step);
    return ranges::views::iota(std::size_t{0}, size + 1) | 
           ranges::views::transform([min, step](auto i) { return min + step * i; }) |
           ranges::to<std::vector>();
}

int main() {   
    auto vec = make_vector(1, .5, 5);
    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';

    // Output: 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5
}
```

Ranges will be a [part](http://eel.is/c++draft/#ranges) of C++20.