# A post-increment operator that allows one to increment at a specified step

Tags: c++, increment, c++20

Which is worse?

Creating copies

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
template<class T>
std::vector<T> range(const T start, const T stop, const T step) {
    int leaps = ((stop-start)/step);
    std::vector<T> output(leaps > 0 ? leaps : -leaps);
    std::generate(output.begin(), output.end(), [i = start, step] () mutable {
        T num = i;
        i+=step;
        return num;
    });
    return output;
}
```

or repeating (I'm assuming a single calculation).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
template<class T>
std::vector<T> range(const T start, const T stop, const T step) {
    int leaps = ((stop-start)/step);
    std::vector<T> output(leaps > 0 ? leaps : -leaps);
    std::generate(output.begin(), output.end(), [i = start-step, step] () mutable {return i+=step;});
    return output;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid both? Something such as a post-increment operator that behaves as `i++` but allows an increment of `step`.

```
// Example
int main() {
    std::vector<double> check_range = range(-4.13, 2.13, 0.25);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected

```
-4.13, -3.88, -3.63, -3.38, -3.13, -2.88, -2.63, -2.38, -2.13, -1.88, -1.63, -1.38, -1.13, -0.88, -0.63, -0.38, -0.13, 0.12, 0.37, 0.62, 0.87, 1.12, 1.37, 1.62, 1.87
```

Comment: Could `T` be a floating point or an integral type?

Comment: Yes it could be both. See edit @Bob__

Comment: You have to profile it yourself. Your specific compiler might be able to do optimizations  one way and not the other. It might also depend on the surrounding context, like architecture. And do you mean worse as in usage of memory or performance or something else? There are many factors so it's not possible to say that one piece of code is worse than another.

Comment: A value of `-4.13` cannot be exactly represented in a floating point variable.   Neither can the results of adding `0.25` to it repeatedly.   If you are expecting exact values of `-4.13`, `-3.88`, etc you will be disappointed

Comment: @Peter I understand and for the purposes of the question wave issues around numerical stability. I guess I am looking for a post-increment operator that behaves as ```i++``` but allows an increment of ```step```. I have included this in the question now as your comment has helped me discover what I actually should of asked.

Comment: *"I guess I am looking for a post-increment operator that behaves as `i++` but allows an increment of `step`. "* That sounds like a task for [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange).

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you, feel free to add an answer. ```std::exchange(i, i+step)```

Comment: Well, there already are some valid answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746846/build-a-vector-with-step-c) ;) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++20, I'd write it lazily:

```
template <class T>
auto range(const T start, const T stop, const T step) {
    return views::iota(0)
         | views::transform([=](int i) -> T{
               return i * step + start;
           })
         | views::take_while([=](T cur){
               return cur < stop;
           });
}
```

If you really want a `vector`, you can eagerly evaluate that, but you probably don't need all of it at once?

---

You could also write a generator using coroutines (though `generator<T>` isn't in the standard library, need to use like cppcoro):

```
template <class T>
generator<T> range(T start, const T stop, const T step) {
    for (; start < stop; start += stop) {
        co_yield start;
    }
}
```

Which, likewise, is a lazy range that can be eagerly evaluated into a `vector` if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`boost::irange`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html). If that doesn't do what you need, you can do some arithmetic.

```
template<class T>
auto range(const T start, const T stop, const T step) {
    int leaps = ((stop-start)/step);
    auto toT = [start, step](int i) { return start + (i * step); };
    return boost::irange(0, leaps > 0 ? leaps : -leaps) | boost::adaptors::transformed(toT);
}
```